# Android TextView on top of a View

Tags: android, view

I have a View that I would like a TextView to pop up over when an event occurs. I have done this before (a long time ago) but can't remember how I did it...

My code is for the View element. Upon adding the TextView, I would like it to show over the top of the View.

```
public class test extends View {
    public test(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }

    TextView tv;

    public void adText(TextView tv){
        this.tv =tv;
        tv.setVisibility(tv.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/

Solves it. Someone delete that wierd comment please...

Comment: In short, the order at which layout is added is the order at which they are displayed (first element added will be at bottom).